# Universal Property of Disjoint Sum topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, universal-property

Let $X$ be the disjoint union of a family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ of topological spaces. Simply put, how do you show the universal property of the disjoint union, so that given continuous maps $f_i : X_i \to Y$, there exists precisely one map $f: X \to Y$ such that the set of diagrams

[image]

commute, where $\phi_i$ denotes the canonical injection from $X_i$ into $X$?

Comment: It follows from the corresponding fact about the underlying sets; you just have to show the function is continuous.

Comment: The heart of this issue is what topology you are endowing $\bigsqcup_{i \in I} X_i$ with. I think the question is hard to answer without thiis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of topological spaces and $X:=\sqcup_{i\in I}X_I=\cup_{i\in I}(X_i\times\{i\})$ be their disjoint union. For each $i\in I$ we have the injection $\phi_i:X_i\to X$ given by $\phi_i(x)=(x,i)$. The topology on $X$ is given by
$$
\{ U \subseteq X \mid
\phi_i^{-1}(U)\ \text{is open in $X_i$ for every $i\in I$}\}.
$$
Clearly this makes each $\phi_i$ a continuous function.
Let $Y$ be a topological space and $(f_i)_{i\in I}$, with $f_i:X_i\to Y$ for each $i\in I$, be a family of continuous functions.
We wish to show that there is a unique continuous function $f:X\to Y$ such that $f_i=f\circ \phi_i$ for every $i\in I$.

In order for a function $f:X\to Y$ to satisfy $f_i=f\circ\phi_i$, we must have
$f(x,i)=f(\phi_i(x))=f_i(x)$ for every $(x,i)\in X$. There is only one function that does this, so it remains to show that the function $f:X\to Y$ defined by $f(x,i)=f_i(x)$ is continuous.
Suppose $U$ is an open subset of $Y$.
To conclude that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, we must show that $\phi_i^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ is open in $X_i$ for each $i\in I$.
Fixing $i\in I$, we have
$$
\phi_i^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))
= (f\circ\phi_i)^{-1}(U) = f_i^{-1}(U),
$$
which is open because $f_i$ was assumed to be continuous.
This completes the proof.